# Create transition effect over psuedo element in css

Tags: css

I am trying to create a manila folder like set of tabs in HTMl. I have achieved the desired look by using psuedo elements. My only issue is, when the user hovers their cursor over the actual "tab" element I want a color to come in from the right to show them that they are hovering over something clickable. My only problem with this approach is my lack of knowledge of psuedo elements.

I have a linear gradient as the background image, and have upped the background-size to only show one half of the linear gradient. As the user hover, the hover css changes the background position to the other color. This effect looks weird with my psuedo element, as it has to have its own rules. How can I achieve the desired effect in one fluid on and off animation??

Here is my code:

```js
const $allTabs = document.body.querySelectorAll('.tab');

for (let i = 0; i < $allTabs.length; i += 1) {
  const $tab = $allTabs[i];

  $tab.style.zIndex = $allTabs.length - i;
  
  $tab.addEventListener('click', () => {
   removeActive();
    $tab.classList.toggle('active')
  })
}

function removeActive() {
  const arrOfTabs = Array.from($allTabs);
 
   const $activeTab = arrOfTabs.find(tab => tab.classList.contains('active'));
  $activeTab.classList.toggle('active');
}
```

```css
.navigation-tab {
    display: flex;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 10px;
    background-color: white;
}

.tab.active {
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    z-index: 90 !important;
    background-image: none;
}

.tab.active::before {
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    z-index: 90 !important;
    background-image: none;
}
.tab.active::after {
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    z-index: 90 !important;
    background-image: none;
}

.tab {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    background-color: white;
    background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, white 0%, white 50%, #005289 50%);
    background-size: 220%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
    transition: all 0.2s;
    transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

.tab:not(.active):hover {
    background-position: 100%;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.tab::before {
    width: 30px;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, white 0%, white 50%, #005289 50%);
    background-size: 280%;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: -20px;
    top: 0px;
    -webkit-transform: skewX(-20deg);
    transform: skewX(-20deg);
    z-index: -1;
    transition: all 0.2s;
    transition-delay: 0.4s;
}

.tab:not(.active):hover::before {
    background-position: 100%;
}

.tab::after {
    height: 100%;
    width: 30px;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, white 0%, white 50%, #005289 50%);
    background-size: 280%;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    right: -20px;
    top: 0px;
    -webkit-transform: skewX(20deg);
    transform: skewX(20deg);
    z-index: -1;
    transition: all 0.2s;
}

.tab:not(.active):hover::after {
    background-position: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
  <nav class="navigation-tab">
  <div class="tab active">Overview</div>
  <div class="tab">New buys</div>
  <div class="tab">Budget</div>
  <div class="tab">Renewals</div>
  <div class="tab">Procs</div>
  <div class="tab">Work for me</div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Just an opinion here, but what you are doing is referred to as "Skeuomorphism UI".  Back in the olden days of UI Design, it was prevalent, but design trends and best practice moved away from it, and was replaced by "Flat design", "Material Design", "Fluent design" and lately the introduction of something dubbed "Neumorphism".  Your design is a throw back to the days of Skeuomorphism, and most designers would shudder.  The complexity doesn't provide you anything that you don't get with any of the UI you get fairly standard in any of the prevailing css frameworks.

Comment: We wouldn't want any designers to shudder!

Comment: You don't have to be a designer, to look at the design idea and see that it's precious, dated, and inconsistent with prevalent standards -- even with the improved version from SamSpade.  I don't know your system, but the nav names seems to indicate a number of functional area will be reached, so the entire idea of a virtual set of folders on a desk doesn't make sense unless this is purely a read only report subsystem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the size of your psuedo element.

First, you only need the ::after pseudo element to achieve this effect. You can remove the gradient backgrounds on the ::before pseudo element and the main element. Next, set the size of that ::after pseudo element so it can actually cover the whole tab. I used a width of 110%. The result will be that the after pseudo element will come in from the right and make it all the way to the left side

Note: this is a lot of code and I don't understand all of it, so I left as much as I could untouched and just removed some of the hover style rules and edited the ::after:hover style rule. I will leave it to you to cut whatever else need to be cut.

Note #2. You have done some messy z-index stuff on the first tab. This meant the text rendered under the ::after element. I have removed the messy z-indexing.

```js
const $allTabs = document.body.querySelectorAll('.tab');

for (let i = 0; i < $allTabs.length; i += 1) {
  const $tab = $allTabs[i];

  $tab.style.zIndex = $allTabs.length - i;
  
  $tab.addEventListener('click', () => {
   removeActive();
    $tab.classList.toggle('active')
  })
}

function removeActive() {
  const arrOfTabs = Array.from($allTabs);
 
   const $activeTab = arrOfTabs.find(tab => tab.classList.contains('active'));
  $activeTab.classList.toggle('active');
}
```

```css
.navigation-tab {
    display: flex;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 10px;
    background-color: white;
}

.tab.active {
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    z-index: 90 !important;
    background-image: none;
}

.tab.active::before {
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    z-index: 90 !important;
    background-image: none;
}
.tab.active::after {
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    background-image: none;
}

.tab {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    background-color: white;
    background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, white 0%, white 50%, #005289 50%);
    background-size: 220%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
    transition: all 0.2s;
    transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

.tab:not(.active):hover {
    background-position: 100%;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.tab::before {
    width: 30px;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, white 0%, white 50%, #005289 50%);
    background-size: 280%;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: -20px;
    top: 0px;
    -webkit-transform: skewX(-20deg);
    transform: skewX(-20deg);
    z-index: -1;
    transition: all 0.2s;
    transition-delay: 0.4s;
}

.tab::after {
    height: 100%;
    width: 30px;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, white 0%, white 50%, #005289 50%);
    background-size: 280%;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    right: -20px;
    top: 0px;
    -webkit-transform: skewX(20deg);
    transform: skewX(20deg);
    z-index: -1;
    transition: all 0.2s;
    width: 110%;
}

.tab:not(.active):hover::after {
    background-position: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
  <nav class="navigation-tab">
  <div class="tab active">Overview</div>
  <div class="tab">New buys</div>
  <div class="tab">Budget</div>
  <div class="tab">Renewals</div>
  <div class="tab">Procs</div>
  <div class="tab">Work for me</div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Better than OP's example, but, this looks also buggy

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I mean, it is buggy. But that's OPs problem, lol. I can only do so much :)

Comment: Yea I'm not sure what that comment's referring to either? If you want it a bit smoother increase the transition time on the pseudo's to like .5s, maybe that's the "also looks buggy" being referenced? Either way +1

Comment: @ChrisW. yes, definitely a +! Good job Sam, and good suggestion by Chris

Comment: Thank you for the help. I think it looks good. As I mentioned I am very new to psuedo elements. Any resources you can recommend to learn more?

Comment: @klaurtar1 first, I'd appreciate it if you could mark it correct, given that you're saying it looks good. As far as pseudo elements go, I'd recommend trying to keep it simple. Don't use more than you need and don't overcomplicate it. They are basically just divs you don't need to put in your html.